# Alert Box question always returning response == 0

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to follow tutorial on tkinter (https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/gui-tkinter-python) and I have just got to the section on responses and message boxes. When i try to run the code, I either get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pack' if I include the .pack() on the end, and/or it says 'Log out now.' whether I click yes or no.

Tried changing response == 1 to response == 0, still happens. I've followed the instructions on the tutorials I could find.

```
import tkinter, time, random
import tkinter.messagebox

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("GUI")

response = tkinter.messagebox.askquestion("Simple Question", "Do you love Python?")
if response == 1:
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Alert Message", "Good person")
else:
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Alert Message", "Log out now")
window.mainloop()
```

I expect the output to be dependent on which answer i choose, but the actual output is always 'Log out now'

Comment: Add a `print(response)` to see what you get and edit your condition `if response == ...` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`tkinter.messagebox.askquestion` return `"yes"` or `"no"`.

So you have to change your code with following string:

```
if response == "yes":
```